# Alternative to looping

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like the following and I am required to show the subtotal of the use_time_sec column grouping by event_datetime, event_name (only show login), user_id and system_id.

[sample input table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwRiO.png)

```
with sample_input as (
    select '12/01/2023 14:27:59' as event_datetime, 'login' as event_name,'1' as user_id, 'X' as system_id, '0' as use_time_sec 
    union all
    select '12/01/2023 14:28:05', 'screen 1',   '1',    'X',    '2'
    union all
    select '12/01/2023 14:28:05', 'screen 2',   '1',    'X',    '5',
    union all
    select '12/01/2023 14:28:17', 'screen 1',   '1',    'X',    '3',
    union all
    select '12/01/2023 14:28:23', 'logout', '1',    '', '0',
    union all
    select '12/01/2023 14:28:23', 'login',  '2',    'Y',    '0',
    union all
    select '12/01/2023 14:28:23', 'screen 1',   '2',    'Y',    '10',
    union all
    select '12/01/2023 14:28:24', 'screen 2',   '2',    'Y',    '100',
    union all
    select '12/01/2023 14:28:29', 'login',  '1',    'X',    '0',
    union all
    select '12/01/2023 14:28:29', 'screen 1',   '1',    'X',    '500',
    union all
    select '12/01/2023 14:28:29', 'logout', '1',    '', '0',
)
select * from sample_input
```

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFxdE.png)

I can loop through the table to get my desired output.  But thats not the most efficient solution as there are few millions of record in the table and growing everyday.

Will appreciate if someone can provide a better solution than what I have.

Note: The data is in google BigQuery.

Thanks

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL Server if you want a query in Google BigQuery?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: "a better solution than what I have"  What do you have?  You provided, a sample of, the input data, and some pictures. But what SQL statement did you use (if any) ?

Comment: Sounds pretty much as the regular DB query homework... anyways, you might want to search for window functions such as `SUM(...) OVER (PARTITION BY...)` and maybe `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` and similar...

Comment: @DaleK I suspect because many people don't realize that sql-server means a specific kind of SQL server.

Comment: There's a logout line with no user_id and no system_id. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as the Gaps and Islands problem. We're trying to identify the islands of user sessions. We need to do a query which gives us some way to identify a session. This relies heavily on [window functions](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/).

One way is to count the number of logins seen per user.

```
select
  *,
  sum(1)
    filter(where event_name = 'login')
    over(partition by user_id order by event_time)
    as session_num
from events
order by event_time
```

That will keep a tally per user_id. It will add to the tally every time it sees a user login.

| event_time | event_type | user_id | use_time_sec | session_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | login | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1001 | things | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 1001 | login | 2 | 10 | 1 |
| 1002 | logout | 1 | 7 | 1 |
| 1005 | logout | 2 | 20 | 1 |
| 1100 | login | 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 1101 | logout | 1 | 10 | 2 |

Now we have a way to identify each user's sessions. We can grouping by user_id and session_num. These are our islands.

```
with sessions as (
  select
    *,
    sum(1)
      filter(where event_name = 'login')
      over(partition by user_id order by event_time)
      as session_num
  from events
  order by event_time
)
select
  min(event_time) as session_start,
  user_id,
  sum(use_time_sec) as total_use_time_sec
from sessions
group by user_id, session_num
order by session_start
```

| session_start | user_id | total_use_time_sec |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1 | 10 |
| 1001 | 2 | 130 |
| 1100 | 1 | 15 |

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/CWA5pmQc) in PostgreSQL, but it should work fine on BigQuery.

Comment: Thank you so much Schwern. That worked. I had to replace filter with IF.

Comment: thanks again.  I have accepted but couldn't upvote your answer as I dont have that privilege yet.